# Move certain lines up using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am wondering how I can move certain lines up in an XML document.

Here is a sample of the text I want to move up

[image: Sample]

I need to move the highlighted fields for each row up 3 rows

Is there a way to quickly do this using notepad++?

Any help will be greatly appriciated. Theres over 10k worth of lines so I am wondering if I can do this a lot faster.

Comment: Record and run a macro.

Comment: which rows exactly want to move and where? it's not clear from your question.

Comment: Rows that begin with <Name> & <Image /> I need to move them up 3 rows before <Path>

Comment: You can bookmark the lines with npp. A simple hotkey script should loop the following: `F2 -> CTRL+SHIFT+UP{3}`. This will find each bookmark and move it up 3 times using the standard npp hotkeys.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a keyboard shortcut to move the lines.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> - Move the current/selected lines up
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> - Move the current/selected lines down

Comment: this is the way to do if there are only a few lines. Unfortunately there are *"over 10k worth of lines"* so this method won't work efficiently

Answer (score 1):

Try RegEx.

- Open *Replace* window
- set RegEx *Search Mode* to "Regular expression"
- enter in *Find what* field:
  `(^\s*?<Path>.*?</Path>\s*?<Protocol>.*?</Protocol>\s*?<UserId>.*?</UserId>\s*?^)(\s*?<Name>.*?</Name>\s*?<Image />\s*?^)`
- and in *Replace with* field
  `$2$1`
- Then press *Replace All*

[image: replace]